# what happens if i choose release my app in xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging, size, release

I recently notice that the debug version of our xcode project is less size than the release version. i cannt figure out what's going on.

The debug version is more or less 150M, and the release version is almost 165M.
The only thing i can think about is we encrypt the png image in release.
I deeply appreciate if anyone can give me any tips.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you check if "debug" only builds the active architecture (and "release" builds all)?

Comment: Encrypting a file (png image) adds no more than one block size (16 bytes for AES) due to padding. Depending on your encryption scheme there may also be an iv, PBKDF2 count and seed added to the encrypted data, the last two probably do not apply to your usage. Encryption will not compress but neither will png files.